# NFS + SMB sharing file locks

Tags: nfs, server-message-block

Is there any way to share file locks between samba(smbd) and nfs(-kernel-server)?

I assume that this is hard to impossible on most linux distributions. The regular smb/nfs implementations have no way of communicating file locks with one another. Is that correct?

I get that NFS permissions/locking differs significantly from SMB. From what I gather there are commercial solutions (such as NetApp, Dell unity/unify, IBM, ..). If I understand correctly, these work on an filesystem abstraction layer, that is shared higher up in the io stack over nfs/smb. Is this achievable in the FOSS realm as well?

Comment: What's the specific use case? Why do you need this particular combination? More detail would help for other people who may visit this question.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the kernel nfs locks and smbd locks are not really play together as the first one implemented in the kernel space, the second one is either in filesystem of smbd itself, thus they don't see/respect each other. The new in-kernel [ksmbd](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/cifs/ksmbd.html) implementation aims address this issue in the future, but currently it's not the case.